# EE6 Multi-Site Manager with Nexcess and Non-Traditional File System?

Tags: php, multi-site-manager, server, index.php

CMS: ExpressionEngine 6
Host: Nexcess Xsmall Plan
Tools: Primarily FileZilla, but terminal-based access as needed

I'm a new (putting it lightly) dev, working with sites and setups touched by 2-3 different senior devs with their own systems for doing things. Now I'm trying to set up a second site branching off a website that's hosted in Nexcess using Multi-Site Manager.

Following the steps from the official documentation (https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/msm/overview.html) I'm not sure how much freedom I have within Nexcess' file system. Here's the current directory situation:

- nexcess-server

  - abc123.nxcli.net *(installation site)*

    - html

      - admin.php
      - index.php
      - .htaccess
    - iworx-backup
    - tnchamber

      - ee
      - user
      - index.html
      - index.php *(file not filled in)*
    - environment.php
  - xyz789.nxcli.io *(secondary site)*

    - html

      - .htaccess
      - index.html
      - index.php *(file created from the index.php file in /abc123/html)*
      - cgi-bin
    - iworx-backup

There are also two unrelated sites on the same server each with their own environment.php file. These environment.php files are - AFAIK so feel free to laugh if they're actually common - a proprietary feature of a third-party development company we contracted with (before I was here).

It contains database info and: "// Universal values that are not environment-specific. These override config.php"

If I understand correctly, due to this file, I can't properly set up the info in abc123.com/admin.php -> URL and Path Settings for xyz789.com. Creating an environment.php file for xyz789.nxcli.io also doesn't have any effect.

I also can't find any specific online documentation about MSM in Nexcess and I'm not really sure how to deal with the file system split up this way (i.e. the index.php in a different directory from the other installation files).

I don't necessarily expect anyone to have the exact complete solution, but I would appreciate any insight or ideas about if this is something quirky with Nexcess or with this environment file.

TIA!

ETA: I didn't actually specify what the "problem" is. I'm stuck on xyz789.com only showing the Nexcess placeholder page no matter what I do. I'm not sure where a point of connection is missing to connect xyz789.com with the site created in abc123.com/admin.php - except for within the URL and Path Settings which are hard-coded by environment.php